# Firebird group by with sum and select max value

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

Table named : tbl_A

```
cname       emp          amount
client1     employeeA    100
client2     employeeA    500
client3     employeeA    200
```

The result should be

```
cname       emp          amount
client2     employeeA    800
```

Reason : client2 which has a max value of amount, 800 the sum of employeeA in all clients.

I have tried using this code

```
select cname, emp, sum(amount)
from tbl_A 
group by cname, emp
```

it gives me different result.

If amount is the same as other client then it will select the first 1.

Is it possible to do it in one line result?

Comment: Please include the actual result in your question and explain your expected result (why is client2 shown and why is the amount 800?). BTW: your query has a syntax error and should yield a token unknown error, please fix it so it shows the actual query used. Also why have you tagged both Firebird 2.5 and Firebird 2.1? Either pick on, or leave both off.

Comment: What if more than one client has the same max amount, ie in your example data, add record `client4     employeeA    500` - what the `cname` should be in the result now?

Comment: `...it will select the first 1` - notice: SQL is a language of sets, and thus there is no "first" or "second" - (in the database, you of course may add your idea of firstiness by adding extra fields, but that would be yours not database's ) - so what you said there was actually "any random one of them", so are you really okay with any? Maybe even different ones while you work with the program,

Comment: what if there would be several different employees ?

Comment: @Arioch'The yes thats the problem too if there are different employees

Comment: @MAC then examples in your questions do not show all of your problem. Add the example with many employees and what the output should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
SELECT
  temp.cname,
  temp.emp,
  (SELECT
     SUM(amount)
   FROM tbl_a
   WHERE emp = temp.emp)
FROM (SELECT FIRST 1
        cname,
        emp
      FROM tbl_a
      ORDER BY amount DESC) as temp
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT
  emp,
  MAX(cname) as cname,
  (SELECT SUM(tbl_a.amount)
   FROM tbl_a
   WHERE tbl_a.emp = temp.emp)
FROM tbl_a as temp
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: another problem what if there are different employees

Comment: @MAC Update question tables, so we can see what you mean. And expected result.

Comment: @MAC check UPDATE